# php fetch multiple array and serialize array from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table for insert files data :

```
|id|url|author|post_id|post_type|timestamp|
```

In `url` field i insert PHP `serialize` data and fetch with this function:

```
function _is_files_list_($id,$type){

$files = mysqli::fetch("SELECT * FROM " . NEWS_FILES . " WHERE news_id = ? AND type = ? ",$id , $type ); 

if (count($files) > 0) {

    $list_files = unserialize($files[0]['url']);
        $count  =   count($list_files[0]);
        for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
            $files_show[]  =   array($list_files[0][$i]);
        }
    return $files_show;

    }
else
{
    return FALSE;
}
}
```

and result :

```
if(($list = _is_files_list_($id,"download")) !== false){

    foreach ($list as $key => $data) {
        echo urldecode($data[0]);
    }
}
```

This worked for me and print/show url field form table but I need to show other table field ie `author` or `timestamp` using this function.

How can I generate this ?

Answer (score 1):

did you tried something like?

```
foreach ($list as $key => $data) {
    echo $data[key]['url'];
    echo $data[key]['author'];
    echo $data[key]['timestamp '];
}
```